# Convert nodejs modules to global

Tags: node.js, module

What if i've installed a bunch of nodejs modules and realized i wanted them to be globaly installed?

Do i need to remove and install them again but this time with -g, or can I convert all my modules to be global in a single line command.

Comment: Simply copying / moving them to the global folder should work.

Comment: Where is the global folder located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many modules intended for global use also include command-line wrappers that are stored/linked in the npm root folder (which should be in your system environment path), I'd suggest you just install them manually using the `-g` option. Otherwise, some packages may not work correctly if you just copy folders.

FYI: The `package.json` file has an optional `bin` property which defines these extra files ([reference](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html)).